# Ubuntu-Emulator doesn't work in a Ubuntu 16.04 VM

Tags: ubuntu-emulator

I have configured a virtual machine with Ubuntu 16.04 32bit. I could successfully install the ubuntu-emulator. But when I command to run the emulator, emulator just appear with a black screen and no more happens after that.

After referring to many sources I verified that Allocated memory and OpenGL support is already available.

How I should troubleshoot this issue.

Comment: What software are you using for the VM? (Virtualbox, VMware..?). Consider using 64 bits kernel. Provide the commands you run on the Ubuntu VM and their output.

Comment: It is an Oracle virtual box. Which commands you mean? Commands related to installing ubuntu-emulator? or ..

Comment: What is an Ubuntu emulator? Are you trying to install Ubuntu in virtualbox?  Or run some emulation within Ubuntu within vbox?

Comment: Actually, this ubuntu-emulator is an emulation environment for Ubuntu Touch OS. It's kind of Android simulator. Currently, I am trying to install it inside an Ubuntu installed virtual box.

Comment: You probably had run something like `sudo ubuntu-emulator create instanceName`. No output after `sudo ubuntu-emulator run instanceName`? Did you try playing around with run parameters? Run `ubuntu-emulator run --help`.

Comment: Yes, you have described exactly what happened to me. Let me try around run command and let you know.

Comment: I tried increasing memory with --memory option and reducing --scale. But still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I tried several times to configure ubuntu emulator in the virtual box but it failed. How ever I could successfully configure and run the emulator following the same steps but inside a dedicated machine.